# jasperreport height band content dependence

Tags: jasper-reports

How to make the report engine adjust band height to fit the real space occupied by content?

In this forum you can find the response if you use the section "pageHeader".
http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=83728

But doesn't work in the "columnFooter" or "pageFooter".

I want to display info on the bottom of the first page without to reserve blank space in the following pages.

Are there any solution¿?

Comment: I know that JasperReport docs says: _Stretching elements in height can be managed very well, due to the section split facility: with very few exceptions (ie the column and page footers)_.  I am looking for other solution

Answer (score 0):

By Ricardo Mariaca. This code is the solution, Thank to Ricardo and Dynamic Report

```
    private void build() {
    try {
        JasperPdfExporterBuilder pdfExporterBuilder = export
                .pdfExporter(PDF_FILE);
        JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilderMain = report()
                .columns(
                        col.column("Item", "item", type.stringType()),
                        col.column("Quantity", "quantity",
                                type.integerType()),
                        col.column("Unit price", "unitprice",
                                type.bigDecimalType()))
                .setDataSource(createSubreportDataSource())
                // .detail(cmp.subreport(createSubreport()))
                .setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataType.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL);

        JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilderDisclaimer = report()
                .setPageFormat(PageType.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE)
                .summary(cmp.subreport(jasperReportBuilderMain))
                .summaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter()
                .setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataType.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL)
                .columnHeader(
                        cmp.text("first page header").setFixedHeight(50))
                .columnFooter(
                        cmp.text(DISCLAIMER).setStretchWithOverflow(true)
                                .setFixedHeight(250))
                .pageHeader(
                        Templates
                                .createTitleComponent("Ricardo Mariaca Approach"))
                .pageFooter(Templates.footerComponent).show()
                .toPdf(pdfExporterBuilder);

    } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private JRDataSource createSubreportDataSource() {
    DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("item", "quantity",
            "unitprice");
    for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
        dataSource.add("Book", (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1,
                new BigDecimal(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

}